# Where to find information about the following Terraform provider attribute deprecation?

Tags: docker, nginx, terraform

I can't find more information in the Terraform provider documentation, neither can I find any open issues in github.

https://www.terraform.io/registry/providers/docs

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+provider+attribute+deprecated

Terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "~> 2.13.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {}

resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
  name         = "nginx:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}

resource "docker_container" "nginx" {
  image = docker_image.nginx.latest
  name  = "nginx"
  ports {
    internal = 80
    external = 8000
  }
}
```

Deprecation:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to the **provider documentation**, not Terraform. The provider is [`kreuzwerker/docker`](https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker) and issues for it would be on its own Github page.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [kreuzwerker](https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker) documentation, you need to change the version in your `required_providers` block:

```
version = "~> 2.21.0"
```

And also, change the way how you're setting the image in the `docker_container`:

```
image = docker_image.nginx.image_id
```

Comment: A sidenote: If you were using an older version and switched to `2.21.0`, you need to run `terraform init -upgrade` after changing the version. Otherwise an error will be thrown when `image_id` is used.